# Can you use Dynamic Factor Analysis with time-series datasets that cover different time periods?

Tags: time-series, factor-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have time series data for several sites and I'm interested in looking at whether the changes in covariates at these sites vary in a consistent manner over the time series.  I thought dynamic factor analysis might be ideal for this type of question, however, the period of time that data is available for all sites varies slightly.  Can DFA handle time series data where there is not perfect overlap in temporal windows within the time series?  If so, can you provide an example?

For example:

- Site A has data in all years from 1980-2005
- Site B has data from 1992-2005
- Site C has data from 1980-1994 and 1998-2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer here, is yes, the `MARSS` package does allow for NA values in timeseries (i.e., when the timeseries do not fully overlap).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).